# Auto Postback not Working

Tags: asp.net, postback, autopostback

I have a combo box which is supposed to reload the page, on change, according to it's new value.

`<asp:dropdownlist id="{ElementId}" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="True"></asp:dropdownlist>`

My problem: It works on and off. After playing around with debuggers I found that there are a few javascript lines which sometimes appear and sometimes don't. Here they are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I'm assuming the .Net generator is responsible for these lines, it seems funny there are times they wouldn't be there. We're working with .Net 4.0.

Moreover, it seems another element is missing when it does not work, a div named "aspNetHidden" is there when it works:

```
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="..." />
</div>
```

When it doesn't work only this appears:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="..." />
```

In addition, on different attempts, seemingly unconnected to the previous issue (it can appear when the previous don't), the `onchange` attribute of the element comes and goes:

```
onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;{ElementId}\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)"
```

Refreshing the page sometimes helps, sometimes not. Is this a common issue?

Comment: I have not seen such an issue, but your id, `{ElementId}` sure looks strange

Comment: Are you changing the `AutoPostBack` property of the control in code? Or some other way causing the control to not be part of the page? It seems that `__EVENTTARGET` and it's companions are only rendered if there are at least one control with AutoPostBack="true" in the page.

Comment: @nunespascal It's not the real id...

Comment: @user1429080 No change. Besides, a simple refresh can fix it - why would the code behave differently?

Comment: Are you using any third party UI controls (e.g. Telerik)?  If you put the following line in OnLoad does the problem go away:             `this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);`

Comment: @Carl, no 3rd party controls. The page is pretty straight forward. Since the occurrence is not stable I can't say yet if it has been overcome. Can you explain what that line does?

Comment: The purpose of GetPostBackEventReference is to return a bit of Javascript to call __doPostBack.  However it has the additional affect of getting Asp.Net to add __doPostBack script and the extra hidden fields (__EVENTTARGET etc) that should be going on when you put the dropdownlist on the page.

Comment: @Carl - something which I assume *should* happen without that...

Comment: Indeed so.  I've seen pages before where it didn't add the postback stuff as expected, but never on and off as you are describing.

Comment: @Carl, I can't figure it out either, but since it hasn't been happening since I've followed your suggestion, I guess I'd accept that as an answer (if you'd post ;) )

Comment: Thank you, but I'd feel a bit of a fraud!  If anyone has the same problem and this helps them they will probably get a more honest representation by reading these comments.  Please let me know if you do ever get to the bottom of it though.